# representing quasicrystal as tilings and appearing frequencies of each tile

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

Quasicrystal can be fully represented either using projection method or tilings with constraints. For the latter, is there some sort of study on the "appearing frequency" of each tile or even appearing frequency on clusters of tiles? Thank you.

Comment: Why the "logic" tag?

Comment: Generally, I think aperiodicity originates from Wang Tile which is a subject of logic....